# jQuery UI Accordion only works for first post: WordPress Custom Post Type

Tags: jquery, wordpress, accordion

Accordion only works for first post...

I know there are similar questions already posted, and after reading through all of them I can't seem to figure out why mine is not working.

I am enqueuing the script in functions.php like so:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'custom-accordion',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/accordion.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

The .js file is like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true, 
                active: false
    });
});
```

The custom post type loop is like so:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div id="accordion"> 

    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3> 

    <div>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

</div> <!--#accordion-->

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The accordion only works for the first post...

Any ideas why?

URL in question: premierdev1 (dot) hcg (dot) bz/prm_faq/

Comment: You can't enqueue styles in the header.  You must enqueue them in your theme functions file, with the [wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action.

Comment: Please see my question's edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Fix:

Just placed the accordion div outside of the loop.  Worked like a charm!

```
<div id="accordion"> 

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <h3><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3> 

                <div>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

</div> <!--#accordion-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You would benefit from using a tool such as Firebug in Firefox.

By viewing your site with Firebug enabled, looking at the Console tab, I am able to see that the reason things are breaking is due to an error:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function

var icons = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "icons" );
```

That code is in your script file here:

http://premierdev1.hcg.bz/wp-content/themes/premier-reverse/js/accordion.js?ver=3.8.1

And the problem is that you can't use the `$` function for jQuery in WordPress, you have to use `jQuery` - unless you are in a document ready function structured like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Do stuff in here, can use $ if you like
});
```

So, to correct this, I suggest changing that file to look like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
    /* Move the below lines into your document ready */
    // getter
    var icons = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "icons" );
    // setter
    $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "icons", { "header": "ui-icon-plus", "activeHeader": "ui-icon-minus" } ); 

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, cale_b.  I have removed the last 2 lines of code completely from the .js file and as you can see the problem still persists.  I believe it's a problem with the jquery not reading the loop.  I added another h3 title and div content like
`<div id="accordion"><h3><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3><div><p><?php the_content(); ?></p></div><h3><a href="#">test 2</a></h3><div><p>test content</p></div></div> <!--#accordion-->` -- and it works for both. I just don't know how to fix.  (sorry for the un-organized code, as it's a comment)